# What happened to questions with 3-4 pending close/reopen votes once the respective thresholds were reduced?

Tags: support, vote-to-close, vote-to-reopen

Recently, the number of close or reopen votes required to close or reopen a question (respectively) was reduced from 5 to 3.

What happened to questions that had 3 or 4 such pending votes when the change took place (not enough to cause an action under the prior scheme)? Were those immediately closed/reopened once the change was made, or was one more vote required to effect a change on such questions? Or were such questions still subject to the prior threshold of 5?

Comment: The ones with 4 close votes required -1 vote to get closed.  We had a good chuckle about it.

Comment: @HansPassant So, if somebody *retracted* their close vote, then said post would have been closed?

Comment: It was an UI bug.  And an organizational bug, new employees making sweeping changes without talking to anybody that understood the consequences.  That one wasn't nearly as funny.

Comment: @AdrianMole As far as I'm aware, retractions don't trigger closures, so it still would have required someone else to cast a close vote. (Which does mean it would have been closed with one fewer vote.)

Comment: @gparyani I was trying to play the pun: -1 required + "-1" for the retraction = success. I guess my humour was less than refined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One more vote is/was required to close them.